# How to set system wide environment variable for jvm.dll

Tags: c, dll, jvm

I have a C file which need to call jvm.dll. When I save the C file in the same folder as jvm.dll (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\bin\server`) it works perfectly fine. 
But When I run the C program from any other location it doesn't work the same. way. 
I used `set LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\bin\server` to call jvm.dll from current directory. 

But when I run the C program from any other location it produces jvm.dll is missing error. 
Please suggest what is equivalent for `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. 
Btw the same program works fine in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the dependencies are in the `PATH` on Windows.